# Connect to card while transaction in hyperldeger

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have run the network using the below command

```
composer-rest-server -c admin@mynetwork -n never -w true
```

In the network there are some other participants also like

Participant1 has p1@mynetwork card

Participant2 has p2@mynetwork card

Now the problem is how to connect to another card while doing the transaction.

I want to do the transaction1 with p1 card and transaction2 with p2 card.

How to do that connection while doing the transaction.
I am using to call the transaction in nodejs by calling 
    http://localhost:3000/api/transaction1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

**1st way:**

You can create an account in github OAuth to authenticate user for your hyperledger rest server. What this does is that your rest-server will then get a wallet where user will upload their card and then activate that card. Now whatever transaction that you will perform will carry on being the participant, whose card that is.

Steps:

1. Export variable COMPOSOSER_PROVIDERS with your github clientID and clientSecret on your terminal.

> export
>   COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{"github":"provider":"github","module":"passportgithub","clientID":"c1e68c173a1*******","clientSecret":"**************a2219abc380fa43ace7519","authPath":"/auth/github","callbackURL":"/auth/github/callback","successRedirect":"
>   ","failureRedirect":"/"}}'

2. Install passport-github

> npm install -g passport-github

3. start composer-rest-server with multiple user mode enabled

> composer-rest-server --card admin@mynetwork -n never -p 3000 -a true -m
>   true

4. Finally authenticate your github account at url

> localhost:3000/auth/github

**2nd way:** (Not Preferable But Easiest :) )

You can create composer rest server at different port using command

```
composer-rest-server -c p1@mynetwork -n never -w true -p 4000
```

Now whatever transaction you want to perform by participant1. Perform on port 4000.

Comment: How to connect with google authentication that can specifies the unique identification of participant. For example here i have a scenario.. I have a angular application that uses the google login at the beginning, at the time of first time login i have to create a card for that participant, so that transactions can be made for individual participant.

Comment: For google authentication, the procedure is similar to that of github authentication. Only things are the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS and necessary libraries to be implemented. For more detail on that, see this link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest